# CanvasJS chart axisX undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvasjs

I have a CanvasJS chart, and I want to set it's stripLine dynamically.

```
chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart",
    {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        legend: {
            fontColor: "#FFF"
        },
        axisX: [{
            title: "Test axisX title",
            stripLines: [
                {
                    value: 250,
                    color: "#FF0000"
                }
            ],
        }],
        data: [] //Later add datapoints
    });
```

Function which set the stripLine's position:

```
var setVerticalLine = function (xPos) {
if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(chart));  //debug info
    console.log("chart.axisX type: " + typeof chart.axisX); //debug info
    chart.axisX[0].stripLines[0].set("value", xPos);
}};
```

After the rendering I call the function, but the set isn't successful.
The error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined...**"
>   The debug info: "**chart.axisX type: undefined**".   The dumped chart
>   object contains the axisX: "..."**axisX**":[{"title":"Test axisX
>   title","stripLines":[{"value":250,"color":"#FF0000"}]}]...

How can be `undefined` the axisX, when I see it on the rendered chart, with the title and stripline? Why am I unable to access it and modify? Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/stripline/set/), '**Chart should be rendered before you can use set method**'. Rendering chart before calling setVerticalLine should work fine in your case.

Here is the working code:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", { 
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  legend: {
    fontColor: "#FFF"
  },
  axisX: [{
    title: "Test axisX title",
    stripLines: [
      {
        value: 250,
        color: "#FF0000"
      }
    ],
  }],
  data: [] //Later add datapoints
});

chart.options.data.push({type: "line", dataPoints: [{x: 200, y: 100}, {x: 300, y: 50}]}); //Dummy datapoints
chart.render();// Render Chart before using set method

var setVerticalLine = function (xPos) {
  if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
    chart.axisX[0].stripLines[0].set("value", xPos);
  }
};

setVerticalLine(220); //Update Stripline value to 220
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart" style="height: 260px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My bad, I think I was not enough accurate. The stripLine modifier function is called from a button handler. When I call it, the chart is rendered, I see it, with the stripLine what is created in the constructor (value:250). The chart object is accessible, I can stringify and dump it. The error is caused by the following line: chart.axisX[0].stripLines[0].set("value", xPos); . The chart.axisX is undefined. As @thepiercingarrow say, only chart.options.axisX exist, which has no setter function. This is against the documentation, what i can't resolve.

Comment: After the first render of chart (i.e. chart.render()), chart.axisX[0] will be accessible and chart.axisX[0].stripLines[0].set() should work fine.

Comment: [@RPeti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7166330/rpeti), You seem to find this issue when there are no dataSeries in the chart (data = [] => no dataSeries present). When there are no dataSeries in the chart, there won't be axis present. Adding a dummy dataSeries (which you can update later) before rendering chart might help you access axisX. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u8fk3dt/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't see `chart.axisX` on the dumped object. What you see is actually `chart.themeOptions.axisX`. Also, `chart.themeOptions.axisX.set` is not a function(, although `chart.themeOptions.axisX.__defineSetter__` is).

Comment: You are right, and you helped me to solve my problem. After 2+ hours of working on it, the setter func(which works according to documentation and answers) still not works. So I modify the options.axisX.stripLine.value, and rerender the chart.